# how to keep sending requests one after the other in nodejs

Tags: node.js, server, backend, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to automate a website, puppeteer session may take about (30s-60s), and I want to fire a request(open another puppeteer session) right after the one before it finishes and I realized that I can't use setInterval because time is not constant in my case, how can I achieve such thing

Comment: `await browser.close()` should complete only when the browser for your session is closed. https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer#usage

Comment: my problem is that I want to immediately fire another instance after the one before it finishes

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive function to keep calling the same function right after it's done.

```
async function bot(){
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  // other code
  await browser.close()
}

async function fireMyRequest(){
  await bot()
  await fireMyRequest()
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it cause a stack overflow?